# SQL server, se truncarían los datos binarios

Tags: sql

Buen día.

Acabo de actualizar un campo de una tabla de una base de 15 de SQL server de nvarchar(10) a nvarchar(15) y quiero introducir un campo de 12 caracteres a la base que actualice, pero me sale el mensaje que puse en el titulo.
La solución sería que reinicie el servicio de SQL, pero no lo puedo hacer ya que las demás base son productivas.
Quisiera saber si hay otra forma de actualizar esta única base sin afectar a las demás, para agregar el dato de 12 caracteres.

De antemano gracias por la atención. Saludos.

Comment: Añade el mensaje de error para poder ayudarte con tu pregunta

Comment: No se puede modificar los datos. Reinicie el server y funciono...
Gracias por responder.